# Do laptops have a POST beeper?

Tags: laptop

I have known about PC speakers to give beep codes, and some people use them to play music. Does this exist in a laptop? If not, what would happen if a program tries to use the PC speaker?

Comment: Even most desktop motherboards don't include a beeper these days, just a header so you can mount your own if you have one.

Comment: My own desktop computer does not have an internal speaker.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the laptop whether it has an internal device to Beep on error cod.

If it does, it will show under Hidden Devices in Device Manager.  It can be disabled there as well.

My laptops (two) do not have internal devices and so use the built-in speakers. No room inside for any extra things.

Other laptops may have internal speakers which can be disabled.

The article below illustrates how to find the speakers and disable them if you have them.

[Laptop internal speaker](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000725.htm)

If you're running Microsoft Windows, you can disable the internal speaker or PC speaker by following the steps below.

> Open the Device Manager
>
> In Device Manager, click View and select Show hidden devices. Once
> done, Non plug and play Drivers becomes visible in Device Manager.
> Expand Non plug and play Drivers by clicking the plus and double-click
> Beep.
>
> In the Beep properties window, click the Driver tab. On the Driver
> tab, if you want to temporarily disable this device, click the Stop
> button. If you want to permanently disable this device, under the
> Startup type, select Disabled.

Any laptop I have used has regular speakers and I think these are the only ones you can use to play any kind of music.

Comment: What happens if a program tries to use the internal PC speaker? Will the laptop beep at full volume?

Comment: The laptop will beep at the volume it is set for.